# Table header only with bootstrap grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to draw this table header only with bootstrap grid system (col-md-x).

I have tried many ways but none of them work.
[image]

If someone has a working solution.  Or maybe the use of col-md-x is not the best solution here.

Thanks
**[UPDATE]**
I did this, I knew it was wrong and that it wouldn't work but it s a start :

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr class="col-md-12">
        <th class="col-md-1">Produit</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Emballage</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Certif Fournisseur</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Certif Entreprise</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Catégorie</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Calibre</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">04/01</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">05/01</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">06/01</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">07/01</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <th class="col-md-6"></th>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <th class="col-md-4">Rsr</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Arr</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Dsp</th>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <th class="col-md-4">Rsr</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Arr</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Dsp</th>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <th class="col-md-4">Rsr</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Arr</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Dsp</th>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <th class="col-md-4">Rsr</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Arr</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Dsp</th>
        </div>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="planning in vm.plannings">
        ....
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Check here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#responsive-tables (also, show us what you've tried to help you best)

Comment: ok, I added one of my tries